# Submit not responding

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, submit

Hello people for some reason, my submit button isn't working. I have tried a couple of ways which I will explain below. Also, I should state that I am using bootstrap modal. I'm not sure if that is the reason why it is acting wired in all ways.

First is my form:

```
<form name="register" action="register.php" method="post">
    <table id="registrationTable" border="0">
        <tr id="registrationTR">
            <td id="usernameTxt">Username:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="username" class="input" name="username" onChange"checkName(document)">
                <br /><p id="registrationInfo">Only alphanumeric, 6-characters minimum</p>
            </td>
            <td id="username_msg" style="color:red;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="registrationTR">
            <td id="passwordTxt">Password:</td>
            <td><input type="password" id="password" class="input" name="password" onChange"checkPassword(document)">
                <br /><p id="registrationInfo">6-characters minimum, case-sensitive</p>
            </td>
            <td id="pwd_msg" style="color:red;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="registrationTR">
            <td>Confirm Password:</td>
            <td><input type="password" id="rePassword" class="input" name="rePassword">
                <br \><p>&nbsp</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="registrationTR">
            <td id="emailTxt">Email:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="email" class="input" name="email" onChange"checkEMail(document)">
                <br \><p>&nbsp</p>
            </td>
            <td id="email_msg" style="color:red;"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Then is my submit button. Please note I've tried two ways, a button and a input type, which both aren't working. Yes I've taken out the validation part for JS with the input type to see if it is working.

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="registerSubmit"  value="Submit" />

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="registerSubmit" onClick="return validateInfo(document)">Register</button>
```

The JS code is just to verify if there's any input within the input fields. At the end, it returns true or false. I'll just show the final piece where it returns true or false:

```
function validateInfo(document) {
    if (checkName(document) && checkPassword(document) && checkRePassword(document) && checkEMail(document)) {
        document.getElementById("register").submit();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I've even tried to use `document.getElementById("register").submit();` to try to submit the form via js, but that didn't work.

Right now, it doesn't even load the php file, so I won't include the php file atm. If needed, I can do that on request.

Any help will be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: register is form name not form id

Comment: make sure your submit button is inside the form

Comment: Where is the submit button? I don't see it inside your form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking for the id "register", but your form doesn't have the id "register":

`document.getElementById("register").submit();`

Try to give your form the id:

```
<form name="register" id="register" action="register.php" method="post">
```

And if it's not working, take a look at your submit-button, if it's inside the `<form></form>` block.